# Is there a standardized way to add location data to rss?

Tags: rss

I have a number of feeds where having the location would be very helpful to others pulling the feed. However, I can't find anything in the spec that describes how location data should be structured.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a standard, but i bookmarked this - when i came across it which may help you out.

http://microformats.org/wiki/location-formats

Answer (score 0):

Geotags aren't part of the base standard for RSS or ATOM, but GeoRSS is the developing standard way for adding this information.  Of course, your users need a reader or script that processes or makes use of the geotags. For example, a standard viewer may simply ignore the tags since it doesn't understand them.  However, there are a number of tools for mappping and such that does understand GeoRSS tags.

For more info, see: http://www.georss.org/Main_Page and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoRSS